# How to use dataloader on ammap

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts, ammap

I am trying to use `dataloader` functionality on [ammap](https://www.amcharts.com/javascript-maps/) but I couldt gain.

Here is how to I try:

```
var dogum_map = AmCharts.makeChart( "il_bazinda_dogum_say_dagilim", {
                  "type": "map",
                  "data": {
                        "map": "turkeyLow"
                    },
                  "theme": "light",
                  "colorSteps": 10,
                  "dataLoader": {
                        "url": "/dogum/dogum_frekans_verilerini_il_bazinda_hesapla",
                        "format": "json",
                        "showErrors": true
                  },
                  "areasSettings": {
                    "autoZoom": false,
                    "balloonText": "[[value]]",
                    "selectable":true
                  },

                  "valueLegend": {
                    "right": 10,
                    "minValue": "En Az",
                    "maxValue": "En Çok"
                  },

                  "export": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "fileName":"İl Bazında Doğum Sayıları"
                  }

                } );
```

There is no problem with json url.This url returns json datas like this:

```
[{"id":"TR-01","ndogum":1111,"mdogum":22,"sdogum":693,"pdogum":336,"total":2162},{"id":"TR-02","ndogum":423,"mdogum":0,"sdogum":325,"pdogum":147,"total":895},{"id":"TR-03","ndogum":199,"mdogum":1,"sdogum":113,"pdogum":42,"total":355},{"id":"TR-04","ndogum":681,"mdogum":17,"sdogum":180,"pdogum":117,"total":995}]
```

I want to use as a `value` on map `total`.

How can I use with `dataloader` on ammap?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the dataLoader with the maps library, your data needs to be the same format as the map's `dataProvider` object, which includes the `map` property and `areas` array. If your data is not formatted that way, then you can use the dataLoader's `postProcess` callback to create a `dataProvider` object and return that along with your data. You also need to remap your total property to value in your data so that your balloon and legend will work.

Here's the dataLoader code:

```
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "/dogum/dogum_frekans_verilerini_il_bazinda_hesapla",
    "postProcess": function(data) {
      var dataProvider = {
        "map": "turkeyLow"
      };
      //create new areas array, while adding a value property 
      //to each area containing the value stored in total
      dataProvider.areas = data.map(function(area) {
        area.value = area.total;
        return area;
      });
      return dataProvider;
    }
  },
```

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e2ae2191e1c371545f63a4eb46228a6a?editors=0010)

Comment: Ok Thanks for Reply